# Microsoft Band 2 - BLE Protocol (communication without SDK)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microsoft-band, gatt

I'm developing a custom desktop application that requires more flexibility then what the current SDK for Microsoft Band is offering (only MS Windows OS, no win32 API, Windows 10 UWP applications are too limiting in background tasks, ecc..).

I just need to read raw data from the Microsoft Band 2 (Heart Rate, Galvanic Skin Response, Accelerometer, Gyro).

I'm exploring the solution of directly communicating to the band using its Bluetooth LE (Smart) services.
I'm able to subscribe to services using some tools for BLE analysis, and it seems that we can read the data.

Moreover reading [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140539/accessing-ambient-light-sensor-on-microsoft-band/32078056) it seems that someone already managed to decode the raw data. Is some unofficial documentation available?

[Image: Raw services screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QNYm.png)